# 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF> perl use Net::SMTP:

Tags: perl, smtp

I'm writting a perl script for sending email and attach zip file but have error

below is error when running code :

```
        Net::SMTP::SSL=GLOB(0x1b79e68)>>> RCPT TO:<ttranquang@tiaxa.as>
        Net::SMTP::SSL=GLOB(0x1b79e68)<<< 250 2.1.5 Ok
        Net::SMTP::SSL=GLOB(0x1b79e68)>>> DATA
        Net::SMTP::SSL=GLOB(0x1b79e68)<<< 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
```

======

```
$msg = MIME::Lite->new(
        To =>'ttranquang@tiaxa.as',
        Subject =>'VTT:Daily Report ['.$TimeDate.']',
        Type    => 'multipart/mixed'
    );
    ### Create a part:
    $part = MIME::Lite->new(
        Top      => 0,
        Type     =>'text/html',
        Data     =>'<H1>Daily Report</H1>',
    );
    $part->attr('content-type.charset' => 'UTF-8');

    $part->add('X-Comment' => 'A report for you');
    $msg->attach($part);
          $msg->attach(
                        Type     => 'application/zip',
                        Path     => '/home/appaxa/scripts/rommel/send_report',
                        Filename => 'dailyreport.zip',
                        Dispostion => 'attachment'
                    );
    $msg->send();

my $smtp;
$smtp = Net::SMTP::SSL->new($host, Port=>465, Debug   => 1,
                           SSL     => 0,) or die "Can't connect";
$smtp->auth($user, $pass)                 or die "Can't authenticate:".$smtp->message();
$smtp->mail('xtime@tel.co')       or die "Error:".$smtp->message();
$smtp->to('ttranquang@tiaxa.as') or die "Error:".$smtp->message();

$smtp->data()                    or die "Error:".$smtp->message();
$smtp->datasend($msg) or die "Error:".$smtp->message();
$smtp->dataend()                 or die "Error:".$smtp->message();
$smtp->quit()                    or die "Error:".$smtp->message()
```

what's the problem here ?? thanks all.

Comment: The debug output does not show any error. 354 is just the normal response to the DATA command. Please add the error you are actually getting (i.e. from your `die "Error...`) and at which statement you are getting this error.

Comment: Re "*what's the problem here*", I could ask you the same thing. You say you're getting an error, but you didn't say what it was.

Comment: There is an extra `\`` after the email address string in the second line.

Comment: The debug output does not show any error but email not sending.. 

if i add some text in $smtp->data()    like $smtp->data(abbb)    i can recived email. 
   
There is an extra ` i remove it from code.

Comment: after i edit code they have new error ;

Net::SMTP::SSL=GLOB(0x15bba60)>>> --_----------=_146371495983980--
Net::SMTP::SSL: Net::Cmd::datasend(): unexpected EOF on command channel:  at send_report.pl line 78.
Net::SMTP::SSL: Net::Cmd::_is_closed(): unexpected EOF on command channel:  at send_report.pl line 79.
Error:[Net::SMTP::SSL] Connection closed at send_report.pl line 79.

======
<br>$smtp->datasend($msg->as_string);

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> $smtp->datasend($msg) or die "Error:".$smtp->message();
> ```

`$msg` is a MIME::Lite object and not a string.
What you want here is a string, i.e. `$msg->as_string`.

Apart from that you are calling `$msg->send` earlier which means that it already tries to send the message via the default transport. This does not really make sense, unless you want to send the message twice.